# Redirecting my react page to a static HTML

Tags: reactjs

I've created a `create-react-app` and I'm trying to redirect to a standard, static html page I have. Here's some code:

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
  <div className="navbar"> 
      <div className="container">
        <div className="logo">My<span>Logo</span></div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li className="log-out"><a href="../../index/index.html">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Right now, it's not working, and just refreshes the current react page. I want it to take me to the static page that is two directories up, into `index/index.html`, and I don't know why it's not working.

I am in the `src` folder of the `create-react-app` inside `App.js`.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds better to implement react routers . and redirect navigate to /. refs https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-react-router-dom/.

example to define your routes :

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles['app']} flex flex-column p-2`} id="app">
      <AppMenu />
      <div className={`${styles['app__content']} p-2`} id="app__content">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route element={<NotFound />} path="*" />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

then, when needed :

```
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    ...
    
 navigate('/')
```

Comment: can you give more detail?

Comment: link added for details

Comment: @sancelot do you mean convert all HTML pages into components(i.e. *.js), and then use the router to route / to the components?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder named "index" in the "/public" folder.
And then put the index.html into the newly created folder.

Change the link as below:

```
<a href="/index/index.html">Log Out</a></li>
```

In react, all static contents are stored in "/public" folder.

Comment: Got it. So if I'm just adding a single react page for a multi-page html site, I gotta move all those other things into public?

Comment: You can move all static content to "/public" folder only.

Comment: how can I get react to then open up another (static) webpage the first time it boots up (i.e, the home page)?